# python: Exception flow: Continue to down catch block after catching?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, except

I am curious if there is a way in python to continue on within try/catch block, after you catch an exception, look at its properties, and if not relevant, then continue down the stack.

```
try:
    # Code
except AppleError as apple_ex:
    # look at 'apple_ex.error_code' error body, and if not relevant, 
    # continue on to next down the catch block...
    # In other words, proceed to except BananaError and so on down.
except BananaError as banana_ex:
    # ...
except Exception as ex:
    # ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AppleError is still an AppleError and not a BananaError, even if error_code is not relevant, so it makes no sense to fall through to BananaError.

You could instead define specific errors for your different error codes:

```
GRANNY_SMITH_ERROR = 1
MACINTOSH_ERROR = 2
class AppleError(Exception): 
    def __init__(self, error_code, *args):
        super(AppleError, self).__init__(*args)
        self.error_code = error_code

class GrannySmithError(AppleError):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(GrannySmithError, self).__init__(GRANNY_SMITH_ERROR, *args)

class MacintoshError(AppleError):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(MacintoshError, self).__init__(MACINTOSH_ERROR, *args)
```

Then you can try to match the specific error:

```
try: raise MacintoshError()
except MacintoshError as exc: print("mac")
except GrannySmithError as exc: print("granny smith")
```

If you do not care to distinguish between different types of apple errors, you can still trap all apple errors:

```
try: raise MacintoshError()
except AppleError as exc: print("generic apple")
```

You can combine these, for example, only doing special processing for GrannySmith, not for Macintosh:

```
try: raise MacintoshError()
except GrannySmithError as exc: print("granny smith")
except AppleError as exc: print("generic apple")
```

The important thing is to list the errors from most specific to least specific.  If you test for AppleError before GrannySmithError, then it will never enter the GrannySmith block.

Answer (score 3):

That is not how exceptions are handled in Python. When you raise an exception in a try block, if you handle catching it in the `except`, it will fall inside that block, but will not continue to the next `except` at that same level. Observe this functional example:

```
try:
    raise AttributeError()
except AttributeError:
    raise TypeError()
except TypeError:
    print("it got caught") # will not catch the TypeError raised above
```

So, in your `try`, we raise an `AttributeError`, we catch it, and then raise a `TypeError` inside catching the `AttributeError`.

The `except TypeError` will *not* catch *that* `TypeError`.

Based on how you are explaining your problem, you need to rethink how you are handling your exceptions and see if you can determine the handling of errors somewhere else, and raise the error *there*.

For example:

```
def some_func():
    try:
        thing()
    except SomeException:
        # analyze the exception here and raise the error you *should* raise
        if apple_error_thing:
            raise AppleError
        elif banana_error_thing:
            raise BananaError
        else:
            raise UnknownException


def your_func():
    try:
        some_func()
    except AppleError as e:
        print('Apple')
    except BananaError as e:
        print('Banana')
    except UnknownException as e:
        print('Unknown')
```

Answer (score 1):

No, that isn't possible. After the exception is handled by the inner `except` it doesn't have the ability to get handled by the outer `except`:

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) on the `try` statement:

> When the end of this block is reached, execution continues normally after the entire try statement. (This means that if two nested handlers exist for the same exception, and the exception occurs in the try clause of the inner handler, the outer handler will not handle the exception.)

In short your only solution might be to have another handler at an outer level and re-`raise` the exception in the inner handler, that is:

```
try:
    try:
        raise ZeroDivisionError
    except ZeroDivisionError as e:
        print("caught")
        raise ZeroDivisionError
except ZeroDivisionError as f:
    print("caught")
```

Now the nested `except` raises an exception which is consequently caught by a similar handler.